# Not able to paste specific files of PowerPoint to new file

Tags: c#, .net, com, powerpoint

I am reading specific slides of my power-point presentation and trying to paste it to new using below code

```
source = ppt.Presentations.Open(filename, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue);

target = ppt.Presentations.Open(targetname, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue);

sourceSlideRange = source.Slides.Count;

for (int i = 3; i < sourceSlideRange; i++)
{
    source.Slides[i].Copy();
    target.Windows[1].Activate();
    target.Slides[1].Select();

    target.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("PasteSourceFormatting");
}
```

but its giving me exception:

> Slides (unknown member) : Integer out of range. 0 is not in the valid range of 1 to 0.`.

My `target` slide is an empty slide. What's wrong here?

Comment: What is the value of `target.Slides.Count`?

Comment: @mjwills Its `0` since i created an empty one

Comment: You cannot select `target.Slides[0]` if there is no slide. Try selection the presentation into which you want to paste a slide.

Comment: Try `target.Slides.Insert(i, source.Slides[i]);` instead of copy paste

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Thanks but `.Insert` is not a available

Comment: Different ppt libaries have different methods and properties. Use Intellisense to find an appropriate way. Something like `target.Presentations[0].Windows[0].Activate();` maybe (instead of `Select`).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I tried to get options like you suggested but not getting the correct method? Any other option or method?

Comment: Probably `target.Windows[0].Activate();`, because `target` is already the presentation. Thought it was the application. Or maybe with index = 1. Sometimes Office applications have 1-based indexes.